# spark 2.1.1 : Parsed JSON values do not match with class constructor

Tags: json, apache-spark, jackson, spark-streaming, json4s

I've a strange problem with `spark 2.1.1` and `json4s.jackson`.

I upgraded my streaming project from `spark 1.5.1`. Now when I execute code in IDE everything works fine.

But after `assembly` and code standalone execution with `spark-submit`

I got the following error

```
Caused by: org.json4s.package$MappingException: Parsed JSON values do not match with class constructor
args=
arg types=
constructor=
```

My Environemnt:

> - spark=2.1.1,
> - scala=2.11,
> - json4s-jackson=3.2.11

Has somebody has faced the same problem before? If yes, how did you solve it?

Many thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/252

Comment: Where is your JSON? Please show an example of the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Seems Like json4s-jackson bug  search in following link "Parsed JSON values do not match with class constructor"

https://recordnotfound.com/json4s-json4s-3177/issues

You need to modify your json

Comment: I can find that bug in the link you've provided. But I don't know what I am supposed to do with it - it doesn't link to any ticket or solution.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to latest Spark vesrion 2.2.x solved the problem. Looks like bug in Spark 2.1.x fixed now in Spark 2.2.x